# url for angular service after migrating to mlab from localhost

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

connecting to mlab:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@ds147890.mlab.com:47890/mean',
  function(err){
  if(err) console.log(error);
  else console.log('connected');
});
```

this is the api point:

```
app.post('/api/register',function(req,res){
//code for register
});
```

now angular service:

```
requestpass(e){
  var email = e;
    return this.http.post('/api/register',{}, 
    {params: {useremail :email}});
}
```

Now angular gives error for post request I have successfully run it for localhost but now I want to migrate to mlab what is the url point i have to use in angular service

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: the above code is changes i have made for mlab

Comment: Try changing the method to `post`. Put should be used for updates only. Hence, `login` component should use `put`, whilst the `register` section should use post. Try that, and see if it returns any error. Also, is Angular running in development, or production mode?

Comment: development mode whole angular code is in one folder  and outside that it is backend code  iam just asking what is the url on angular service i have to use

Answer (score 0):

I see you have used the API url in post

```
return this.http.post('/api/register',{}, 
    {params: {useremail :email}});
```

but where the full path of your API?, 
for example:

```
return this.http.post('IP_OR_DOMAIN_NAME'+'/api/register',{}, 
    {params: {useremail :email}});
```

Have you tried to connect with API through the postman?